# rails delete has_one :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following data relationships:

```
model A has_one B, :through => C
model A has_one C, :dependent => :destroy

model B has_many C, :dependent => :destroy
model B has_many A, :through => C

model C belongs_to A
model C belongs_to B
```

let's say I have object a (type A) and object b (type B) and a.b = b,
I want to remove the association.

what i'm currently doing is b.as.delete(@a), it removes the row from the C table, but a.b stays valid, even if I try to do a.b = nil it stays valid with the old value.

I just found out that if it happens only if I add the association by a.b = b
if I add it by doing b.as << a, everything is working fine as expected when deleting..

what am I doing wrong ?

update - if i do a.reload the value is updated to nil also in the case i created the association with a.b = b, i don't want to use reload to get the correct value.
why does it happen only in this case and not in the b.as << a case ?

Comment: I have just asked a similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516457/rails-delete-has-one-through-association

Answer (score 1):

The active record `delete` method only deletes the row of the object you are referencing, and does not respect your `:dependent => :destroy` relationship.

What you want to do is use the `destroy` method instead, and this will also propogate the destroy through as you have defined.

Comment: i don't want to destroy any object, just the relationship

Comment: I don't think this answer helps